# SQL - Get value based on a condition per entity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table defined as :

| Entity | Version | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | current | null | null |
| a | last_year | 50 | 100 |
| b | current | 25 | 100 |
| c | current | 40 | 100 |
| c | last_year | null | null |
| d | current | 50 | 100 |
| d | last_year | 55 | 200 |

I want to extract `Value1` and `Value2` for each entity whenever there is a value but preference for 'Version = Current'. So, for the above example, the answer should be:

| Entity | Version | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | last_year | 50 | 100 |
| b | current | 25 | 100 |
| c | current | 40 | 100 |
| d | current | 50 | 100 |

Comment: If the preference is for version = 'current' then why is `a` not also current with `null` and `null`?

Comment: What I meant by is 'always get the positive values of value1 and value2' and if data exists in both versions for an entity, take the values for the 'current' version

Comment: What if value1 is NULL and value2 is not NULL

Comment: good point. Then take non-null value1  and non-null value2. I guess that complicates it. 
Essentially all I want is the non-null values for value1 and value2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical use-case for *row_number*, the only complication being the ordering criteria.

Assuming You want rows with both values being `null` to have the lowest rank, try the following:

```
select Entity, Version, Value1, Value2
from (
    select *,
        Row_Number() over(partition by entity 
                          order by 
                            case when Concat(value1,value2) = '' then 1 else 0 end,
                         version) rn
    from t
)t
where rn = 1;
```

See [Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/f9uv9B1i)